# Change name of NUnit test

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I want my unit-tests based on `NUnit` framework named a bit more human readable in Visual Studio test explorer.

For example instead of having `Test_Case_1` or `TestCase1` I would better have something like `Test Case #1, Category: First, Category: Second` (by assigning values from `[Category]` attributes as well), with spaces and characters not allowed in methods names.

I know it's out-of-the-box possible in `xUnit`, but I cannot involve it, since I'm using my customizations that I was not able to implement using `xUnit` framework.

Is it possible to rewrite unit test display name with `NUnit`? So far I can see, that `FullName` field of `TestDetail` has private setter.

Is any other ways or approaches change display name for `NUnit` tests?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is supported if you are using parametrised tests, you can specify the `TestName` when adding the `TestCase` attribute.

If you aren't using [TestCase](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.5), then you could use it as a less than ideal work around to achieve what you're trying to do.  So you would declare your test like this:

```
[TestCase(null,TestName="Test Case #1, Category: First, Category: Second")]
public void TestCase(object ignored)
```

This isn't ideal because it's not programmatic so you have to manually type the test name, rather than generating it from the attributes on the test method.  You also have to pass a parameter to the method, which is what the `ignored` and `null` is about.  Of course, you could start using parametrised tests in which case you'd be passing in an actual value to your tests.

```
[TestCase(5,TestName="Test Case #1, Category: First, Category: Second")]
public void TestCase(int someInput) {
    Assert.AreEqual(5, someInput);
}
```

Comment: You're right... This is the only possible way for now... However, I've submitted [issue](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/688), So maybe the default behavior will change in the future.

Answer (score 8):

You can create your own Name attribute:

```
// I used the same namespace for convenience
namespace NUnit.Framework
{
    public class NameAttribute  : NUnitAttribute, IApplyToTest
    {
        public NameAttribute(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public void ApplyToTest(Test test)
        {
            test.Properties.Add("Name", Name);
        }
    }
}
```

You then use it like a regular NUnit property (Just like Category and Description).

```
[Test, Name("My Awesome Test"), Category("Cool.Tests"), Description("All cool tests")]
public void Test313()
{
    // Do something
}
```

You can see the data in your TestContext:

```
if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties.ContainsKey("Name"))
{
    name = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties.Get("Name") as string;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Further to @forsvarir answer above, the following now works (from at least 3.6.0, possibly earlier):

```
[TestCase(TestName = "Test case name")]
public void TestSomething()
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: I took in my case `nameof(..)` to show the actual name of tested method, so `[TestCase(TestName = nameof(TargetClass.MethodToTest))]`

Comment: @Rekshino, `[TestCase(TestName = nameof(TargetClass.MethodToTest))]` is printing the method name instead of executing the method and using it's return value. What am I missing here?

Comment: @Mounika - "...is printing the method name instead of executing the method." According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof), it works that way because that's literally what the `nameof` expression does. More details in my answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71780944).

Comment: Could you specify the version of NUnit when you did that? Because in mine, 3.13.3, I can't.

Comment: @Master Djon, interesting - I've just checked (and updated) at it's at LEAST 3.6.0, possibly earlier - can you double check that you've updated the version?

Comment: @ImmortalBlue Finally, it is there. I probably was using `TestCaseSource`. Not sure. Well, at least, now the version is specified. :)

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to change the test name of a parameterized NUnit test programmatically and dynamically, i.e. based on input files in a test data folder.

It took a couple of adjustments, but this works:

```cs
[Test, TestCaseSource(nameof(GetSites))]
public void TestForEveryFile(object ignored, FileInfo testFile) {
   // actual test using 'testFile'
}

public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> GetSites()
{
    foreach (string testFile in Directory.EnumerateFiles("TestData"))
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(testFile);

        // Pass '' as first argument to TestCaseData to suppress the default test name
        // (seems to be necessary even if TestName is set)
        var testCase = new TestCaseData("", fileInfo) 
        {
            // Use the short file name as test name.
            // As dots (.) would indicate a test hierarchy, we replace them with '-'.
            TestName = fileInfo.Name.Replace(".", "-")
        };
        yield return testCase;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible way is to create your own `TestAttribute` class and set the property `Name` of the `NUnit.Framework.Internal.TestMethod` instance to whatever text you want to display (see method `TestAttribute.BuildFrom` in the code below).

Please be aware that this code is no more than a hack. It might cause side effects that I haven't thought of.

```cs
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using NUnit.Framework.Interfaces;
using NUnit.Framework.Internal;
using NUnit.Framework.Internal.Builders;

namespace NUnitTesting.Tests
{
    [TestFixture(TestName = "Display name of Tests")]
    public class Tests
    {
        [Test(DisplayName = "Display name of Test1")]
        public void Test1()
        {
        }
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class TestAttribute : NUnitAttribute, ISimpleTestBuilder, IApplyToTest, IImplyFixture
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The author of this test.
        /// </summary>
        public String Author { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Descriptive text for this test.
        /// </summary>
        public String Description { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The display name for this test.
        /// </summary>
        public String DisplayName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the expected result.
        /// Not valid if the test method has parameters.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The result.</value>
        public Object ExpectedResult
        {
            get => this.expectedResult;
            set
            {
                this.expectedResult = value;
                this.hasExpectedResult = true;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The type that this test is testing.
        /// </summary>
        public Type TestOf { get; set; }

        #region IApplyToTest Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Modifies a test by adding a description, if not already set.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="test">The test to modify.</param>
        public void ApplyToTest(Test test)
        {
            if (!(test.Method is Object))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("This attribute must only be applied to tests that have an associated method.", nameof(test));
            }

            if (!test.Properties.ContainsKey(PropertyNames.Description) && this.Description != null)
                test.Properties.Set(PropertyNames.Description, this.Description);

            if (!test.Properties.ContainsKey(PropertyNames.Author) && this.Author != null)
                test.Properties.Set(PropertyNames.Author, this.Author);

            if (!test.Properties.ContainsKey(PropertyNames.TestOf) && this.TestOf != null)
                test.Properties.Set(PropertyNames.TestOf, this.TestOf.FullName);

            if (this.hasExpectedResult && test.Method.GetParameters().Length > 0)
                test.MakeInvalid("The 'TestAttribute.ExpectedResult' property may not be used on parameterized methods.");
        }

        #endregion


        #region ISimpleTestBuilder Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Builds a single test from the specified method and context.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="method">The method for which a test is to be constructed.</param>
        /// <param name="suite">The suite to which the test will be added.</param>
        public TestMethod BuildFrom(IMethodInfo method, Test suite)
        {
            TestCaseParameters parms = null;

            if (this.hasExpectedResult)
            {
                parms = new TestCaseParameters();
                parms.ExpectedResult = this.ExpectedResult;
            }

            var testMethod = this.builder.BuildTestMethod(method, suite, parms);
            testMethod.Name = this.DisplayName;
            return testMethod;
        }

        #endregion

        private readonly NUnitTestCaseBuilder builder = new NUnitTestCaseBuilder();

        private Object expectedResult;
        private Boolean hasExpectedResult = false; // needed in case result is set to null
    }
}
```

This way, at least the Visual Studio Test Explorer shows "Display name of Test1" instead of just "Test1":

[image: Visual Studio Test Explorer]

However the test runner/explorer of ReSharper still uses the method's name:

[image: ReSharper test Explorer]