# Name of test in NUnitTestAdapter 2.1.1 NUnit 2.6.4

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, nunit, nunittestadapter

Is there any way to change test names displayed in Test Explorer for NUnitTestAdapter 2.1.1/NUnit 2.6.4?

Currently test name is just method name. Because I have some base classes with tests and multiple inherited classes, it is impossible to figure out for which class test fails.

[image: Test Explorer]

I know there is [Template Based Test Naming](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Template-Based-Test-Naming) in NUnit3, but is there anything in NUnit2? When tests are run from console Full type name is displayed:

```
GcmSetup.Tests.TestSetup.DataHandling.Converters.TestConverterTests.MappingDataRecordConverterTests`1.Mapping_ColumnIsUnique
GcmSetup.Tests.TestSetup.DataHandling.Converters.TestingInfoFieldsTab.TestingInfoFieldConverterTests.MappingDataRecordConverterTests`1.Mapping_ColumnIsUnique
GcmSetup.Tests.TestSetup.DataHandling.Converters.TestingProtocolTab.TestProtocolActionConverterTests.MappingDataRecordConverterTests`1.Mapping_ColumnIsUnique
```

Comment: could this be helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799691/change-name-of-nunit-test

Comment: Unfortunately no. Using TestContext and changing name of TestSetupData in SetUp metod did not help.I can not set static name as I want to have name with actual class name