# Change TestName in NUnit

Tags: c#, nunit

I am trying to change the testcase name as below:

```
    public static string getTestName()
    {
        return testName;
    }

    [TestCase(TestName = nameof(getTestName))]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        
    }
```

This is updating my testcase name to "getTestName" instead of executing getTestName function and using it's return value.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The expression `nameof(getTestName)` returns "getTestName". In C#, arguments to an attribute constructor must be constants.

Comment: Might be a basic question. When you say attribute constructor, is it about "nameof" ? 
Also, how to get this working as expected?

Comment: This: `[TestCase] invokes the constructor of the `TestCaseAttribute` class. Adding `TestName=nameof(getTestName)` sets the `TestName` property of that attribute to a particular string. C# syntax for attributes is weird! It's also limited.

Comment: I'd need more info to actually answer your question (I know because I tried). So I only commented. It's not clear what you are trying to do in your test. Will it be called multiple times? What are the arguments? How do you want to construct test names for each call... i.e. using what data? You can edit your question to add that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

[According to Microsoft:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof)

> A `nameof` expression produces the name of a variable, type, or member as the string constant:

So `nameof(getTestName)` is an expression that evaluates to the name of the `getTestName` method. The result of this expression is the string `"getTestName"`. This expression does NOT invoke the `getTestName` method, as you seem to think it should.

You need to pass a constant to the `TestCase` attribute:

```cs
public class MyTests
{
    [TestCase(TestName = "One Option")]
    public void OneOption()
    {
    }

    private const string TestName = "Another Option";
    [TestCase(TestName = TestName)]
    public void AnotherOption()
    {
    }
    
    // This will evaluate to "MyTests", which is the name of the class passed to the nameof expression.
    [TestCase(TestName = nameof(MyTests))]
    public void YetAnotherOption()
    {
    }
}
```